# How can i get my nic card to work in 10.10 throght the terminal?

Tags: wireless, networking, 10.10, nic

I am running ubuntu **10.10** and I can not update it until I have my wireless working. Mostly because my Ethernet is not strong enough to get the update packages.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 10.10, you've got several upgrades that need to happen across a lot of versions that are now discontinued (10.10→11.04→11.10→12.04). That's the bare minimum for getting to a supported version. If you've already got connection issues, that's a lot of upgrading. That's hours-to-days depending on the connection speed.

It would take less time and less bandwidth if you just reinstalled with the version you want to use now. Download the CD with a torrent (to ensure it's not corrupted - great on bad connections) and then burn it to USB or CD.

I'd *strongly* suggest trying it before you install (to see if the kernel included is loading the right drivers, etc) but yeah... An install shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes and after that you're back in the land of supported software.